# Will a commit on a git branch follow if I do a push from another branch?

Tags: git

I have a git branch that I have just committed a large project on. I want to retain that project's committed work, but go make a change to a single file on another branch and push only that change up. When I do I 'git log' on the second branch though, it's still showing me the commit I did from the first branch. If I make a change to a file on the second branch and commit and push that, will my push also contain my first branch's commit as well? (Very undesired!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the log shows the original commit, it's there. If you don't want that, you can

1. checkout the main branch.
2. run `git checkout HEAD~1` to checkout the commit *before* your last commit.
3. check out a new branch `git checkout -b my-new-branch` (which will now be based on the commit-before-the-one-you-just-made) and put your other file changes on that.

Comment: Thanks so much for that advice! If I do the git checkout HEAD~1, won't I lose all my work or will it basically just give the appearance of all that work simply not having been committed?

Comment: You won't lose your work. You are just changing the internal pointer to the previous commit.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. How is this any different than a git reset --soft HEAD~1?

Comment: If you are worried about losing a commit, you can always run `git reflog` which shows a list of all the things that have just happened. That will include regular commits, but also the hashes of other movements (those can be ignored).

Comment: `git reset --soft HEAD~1` will mark the work done after the previous commit as "uncommited" (that's what the *reset --soft* does). Also it tell git that the `HEAD` should actually be at the previous commit. So then if you did a `git checkout HEAD` it would now point to the previous commit. Whereas, `git checkout HEAD~1` just moves the pointer.

Comment: Okay...so, I did the git checkout HEAD~1 and that certainly allowed me to commit and push just the single file change I wanted. Now how do I get all my big project work back? git checkout <hash from reflog> of the original commit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215205/discussion-between-skittles-and-jakeparis).